# Bind data on props on VueJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, bind

I have a component called RpContainer which will receive data by its props called 'completeReport' like that :

```
export default {
    props: ['completeReport'],
    created() {
    }
}
```

This component is used in my main Vue called Report like that :

```
        <RpContainer v-if="displayReport == true" :completeReport="indicatorList"></RpContainer>
```

In my main Vue, I'm doing some API calls to get some data, with those data, I built an array (indicatorList). And what I want is to link this array once it's completly done (there is a delay between my call and the answer) with my props 'completeReport'.

But the problem is that when my component RpContainer is created, my array is still empty. So how could I link it properly to have an update in my component when my array is succesfully build.

I tried to put a watcher my props but it's not working..

Can you help me ? Thanks

Comment: How are you updating your indicatorList? Are you sure it's not linked to any of the change detection caveats: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

Comment: I'm updating it with push method cause I already faced the problem your link is talking about. Cause when I print it at the end of the API call, it's fully completed (I used JSON.stringify to be sure of that)

Comment: You should try and give a minimal reproduction of your problem, it's pretty hard to debug with so little information

Comment: Can you add your code? it's hard to understand what you are trying to do.